# How to set columns when using helpers in pg-promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, pg, pg-promise

Developed by node.js. I am using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

There is a problem with inserting the following data.

I want to insert multiple rows of data into the table below.

```
create table info (
  id varchar(20) not null,
  name varchar(20) not null,
  createdate timestamp with time zone not null
)
```

I inserted the data below.

```
let info = [
  { myid: '0001', myname: 'name1' },
  { myid: '0002', myname: 'name2' },
  { myid: '0003', myname: 'name3' },
]
```

I originally inserted the following.

```
for (let i = 0; i <info.length; i ++) {
  db.none (`INSERT INTO info (id, name, createdate ') VALUES ($1, $2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`, [info[i].id, info[i].name])
}
```

I want to fix it correctly using pg-promise.

```
const dataMulti = info
const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(
[
  'id',
  'name',
  'createdate',
], {
  table: 'info',
})
await db.none(pgp.helpers.insert(dataMulti, cs))
```

Here,

**1. Can not insert when the key of the insert data is different from the . columns name of the table?**

> I know there is pgp.helpers.ColumnSet()
>
> Error: Property 'id' does not exist.
>
> The same error occurs.
>
> I am curious about the relationship between table column names and
>   ColumnSets for column settings.

**2. When using the helpers above, how do I insert the current time current_timestamp in the database?**

Thank you for your answers to the two questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following [ColumnSet](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html) corrects all your problems:

```
const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet([
    {name: 'id', prop: 'myid'},
    {name: 'name', prop: 'myname'},
    {name: 'createdate', mod: '^', def: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'}
], {
    table: 'info'
});
```

See [Column](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.Column.html) for what's available to configure individual columns.

> the application of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is difficult to understand...

```
{name: 'createdate', mod: '^', def: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'}
```

It is a column named `createdate`, with default value `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and formatting modifier `^` (same as `:raw`), which means raw text (no escaping needed). Other than that, [Column](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.Column.html) type explains it in detail.

Comment: Thank you very much. I now know that this is a feature. **However, the application of current_timestamp is difficult to understand.** Can I ask for a little more explanation?

Comment: I do not know how to initialize 'rawText'.

Comment: @hyeokluv No such thing as `rawText` in my answer ;) You should use the latest, it was simplified ;)

Comment: *As a more detailed answer to your question, I am able to use it properly.* pg-promise is a really useful module. thank you.