# Convert a ColumnSet column into geometry with pg-promise

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I'm creating a [ColumnSet](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html) object with pg-promise, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260641/how-to-set-columns-when-using-helpers-in-pg-promise):

```
const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet([
    {name: 'Id',prop: 'Id'},
    {name: 'Lat',prop: 'Lat'},
    {name: 'Lng',prop: 'Lng'},
    {name: 'CreationDateTime',prop: 'CreationDateTime'},
    {name: 'Topic',prop: 'Topic'},
    {name: 'UserId',prop: 'UserId'},
    {name: 'shape',mod: ':raw',prop: 'shape',def: 'point'},
    {name: 'UserName',prop: 'UserName'},
    {name: 'appName',prop: 'appName'},
    {name: 'appVersion',prop: 'appVersion'}
], {
    table: 'Location'
});
```

`def: 'point'` point is method to converting into geometry-- This is a value or how can i run point method and do bind in this column (shape) ?

and write this method for bulk inserting :

```
async function insertMany(values) {
    try {
        let results = await db.none(pgp.helpers.insert(values, cs));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

for converting lat and lng i wrote this method :

```
const point = (lat, lng) => ({
    toPostgres: () => pgp.as.format('ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($1, $2), 4326)', [Lag, Lng]),
    rawType: true
});
```

But I got this error:

```
TypeError: Values null/undefined cannot be used as raw text
```

According this [page](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/formatting.html):

> Raw-text variables end with :raw or symbol ^, and prevent escaping the text. Such variables are not allowed to be null or undefined, or the method will throw TypeError = Values null/undefined cannot be used as raw text.

When point method is not executed, of course that shape filed is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you are misusing option `prop`, which [is documented](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.Column.html) as to be used when the destination property name differs from the column name, which is not your case.

And `def`, as documented also, represents the value when the property is missing. When the property is there set to `null` or `undefined`, the value of `def` isn't used.

You are trying to override the resulting value, that means you need to use property `init`.

Another issue - your variables inside `point` implementation switch cases.

In all, your code should look something like this:

```
const getPoint = col => {
    const p = col.value;
    // we assume that when not null, the property is an object of {lat, lng},
    // otherwise we will insert NULL.
    return p ? pgp.as.format('ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(${lat}, ${lng}), 4326)', p) : 'NULL';
};

const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet([
    'Id',
    'Lat',
    'Lng',
    'CreationDateTime',
    'Topic',
    'UserId',
    {name: 'shape', mod: ':raw', init: getPoint},
    'UserName',
    'appName',
    'appVersion',
], {
    table: 'Location'
});
```

And version that uses [Custom Type Formatting](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#custom-type-formatting) would look like this:

```
const getPoint = col => {
    const p = col.value;
    if(p) {
        return {
            toPostgres: () => pgp.as.format('ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(${lat}, ${lng}), 4326)', p),
            rawType: true
           };
    }
    // otherwise, we return nothing, which will result into NULL automatically
};

const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet([
    'Id',
    'Lat',
    'Lng',
    'CreationDateTime',
    'Topic',
    'UserId',
    {name: 'shape', init: getPoint},
    'UserName',
    'appName',
    'appVersion',
], {
    table: 'Location'
});
```

Comment: I got this error `ReferenceError: getPoint is not defined` when i am using first recommended . this is my codes http://codepad.org/vRWRZjIX  @vitaly-t

Comment: @sayreskabir that's a JavaScript error, you are trying to use a `const` value before it is defined. You can see that in my code `getPoint` is defined before it is used, not the other way round. If you want it the other way round, you'd need to change it into `function getPoint(col)`

Comment: Thanks master. @vitaly-t